# Google maps intermittent quota exceeded message

Tags: google-maps

Since last friday, without having changed any code on my website or Google API Console, we started getting the following message:

*"This site has exceeded its daily quota for maps. If you are the creator of this site, please visit the documentation to learn more".*

What we can't explain is the following:

1. The Google API Console reports we are well under the maps daily quota
2. Users get this messages intermittently. If you get the message, for example, and reload the page, you probably wont get the message again.
3. We started getting an unrelated issue saying that the current site wasn't authorized to use the API. But the whole domain was authorized via the API console, has been authorized for over a year, we haven't touched that setting, this issue is also intermittent.

Any clue as to why is this happening and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Do you implement some interval to request google.maps? What delay do you have for send a request after the other?

Comment: No intervals. Just a website with maps. We have several subdomains, but they are all authorized by having authorized the root domain. Plus, please see above where the console reports us not being even close to reaching quota limits. Also we use an API key to ensure we get reporting for our usage.

Comment: We're seeing the same problem on our site - intermittent quota errors, but seemingly no problems on the console. Have you heard any reports from external users seeing this, or is it just your internal team?

Comment: Im sad to hear you have the same issue, but I'm somehow glad we are not alone. Getting reports from end users is usually a slower process, but several people in the company we are developing for have reported seeing the issue. I found this bug report, opened in June and still labeled as "new": https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6756&can=6&q=quota&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal